# How to add a new GIT server in a deployed repo

Tags: git

I have a Laravel website in a repo on server A.
Now I have already moved this repo to server B.
Both repos are up to date.

This repo is currently checked out and displayed on my server (web server).
Now I would like to change the Origin on server B accordingly.
Is it enough to simply adjust the .git/config or do I need to pay attention to anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git remote set-url origin $NEW_URL` will replace the URL for the `origin` remote.

`git remote add server_b $NEW_URL` will add a brand new remote, named `server_b`, alongside the existing remote(s).

Don't forget to keep Apache/nginx/whatever from sharing your `.git` folders!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply adjust the `.git/config` without any need to pay attention.

Check the following sample `.git/config` below:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://your.repo/path/to.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

The `[remote "origin"]` and it's `url` is all your need to switch to another repo url.